# PhpDoc: <static> in trait methods refers to trait instance

Tags: php, phpdoc, typechecking

I'm having an issue in type-checking some methods of a trait.
I'm using a sort of facade-pattern and my aim would be to inject some methods of a facade in other classes through a trait that has generic declared methods with the return type of the class that uses the trait.

This is the structure of my project:

```php
/**
 * This class has the methods I would like to inject in other classes with a trait.
 * The return type of these methods should refer to the class that uses the trait.
 *
 * @template T
 */
class MyFacade {
  /**
   * @return T
   */
  public function facadeMethod() { ... }
}
```

```php
/**
 * This the trait that injects methods in those classes that use it. 
 * The return type of these methods has to be the type of the facade, 
 * infering in it the type of the class.
 */
trait MyTrait {
  /**
   * @return MyFacade<static>
   */
  static function traitMethod() { ... }
}
```

```php
/**
 * This class uses the trait.
 */
class MyClass {
  use MyTrait;
}
```

So when i write:

```php
$result = MyClass::traitMethod()->facadeMethod();
```

I would like `$result` to be of type `MyClass`, but the IDE says that the type is actually `MyTrait`, so it suggests me properties and methods of *all the classes* that use the trait, and this is useless for me.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Does your IDE support adding this information through for example annotations?

Comment: Which IDE says that? Point is, this may well depend on that, and less on the code you wrote. What does e.g. Psalm or PHPStan think of this?

Comment: The IDE is PhpStorm and usually works fine for type-checking with PhpDoc. If I use static::class inside the @return MyFacade<?> of the trait's method it doesn't work because of bad syntax. Returning $this on facadeMethod actually suggests the properties of MyFacade, but I'd need MyClass properites instead